# First used row in my selected column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to clear all cells in my worksheet from first used to last used row in my selected column, but first I must know the first used row in my selected column. How can I find the first row in "X" column? (X may =  {A, B, C, ...})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
firstUsedRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
```

Where the second argument in `Cells(1, 1)` is the column number (e.g., A=1, B=2, etc.). `Sheet1` is the worksheet name of the worksheet in question.

It is possible, though unlikely in your case, that the first row is row 1. In this case, the above code will actually select your last row of the used range. As a safety measure for this case, identify the last row and make sure your first row is either 1 or the row generated by the above code. So

```
finalRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
if finalRow = firstUsedRow then
    firstUsedRow = 1
End If
```

All together

```
firstUsedRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
finalRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
if finalRow = firstUsedRow then
    firstUsedRow = 1
End If
```

Comment: perfect answer +1.

Comment: @Pisti - This *may* get you the the first row with data for a column, or it may not. If A1 is the first cell with data and the data runs contiguously to say A10, you will get `A10` as the first used row with data with this method, which is obviously wrong. I suggest `IF Len(.Cells(1,1) Then firstUsedRow = 1 Else firstUsedRow = ... (rest of answer above) End If`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman this is a good point, one worth motivating an edit to my answer.

Comment: @MattCremeens - I would handle it a bit differently. The edited answer will still fall if `A1` and `A2` have data, `A3` does not and `A4` does. It will return `A2` as the first row when it's not. See my suggestion in my comment above for what ( I think) is the best approach).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Fair enough, though it appears as though the OP's data is rather predictable and consists of data starting at some row greater than 1 and proceeding continuously to some last row.

Comment: @MattCremeens - I agree. I was stressing the point more for people who come afterwards :)

Comment: Yeah I got that experience, the first code is not perfect but the next it is. Thank you both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see the code below. It will skip over all the blank rows in column A represented by second argument of Cells as 1. Then assign the row positions for variables firstRow and lastRow. Last clear the values from that range.

```
Sub ClearCells()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1) = ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    firstRow = i
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(Cells(firstRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good solution but I want to avoid loop because i have 12000 row, and If that loop every time circuit and search the first used row I am cut my throat. But thx the answer, That is a good stuff too. :)

Answer (score 0):

See below with no loop.

```
Sub ClearCells()
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    firstRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(Cells(firstRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).ClearContents
End Sub
```